# Cannot Login To phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, lamp, phpmyadmin

I'm running a simple LAMP server at home from which I host a personal blog. The server is running Arch Linux, with the latest-and-greatest versions of Apache, MySQL, and PHP. In order to easily maintain the databases, I installed phpMyAdmin. However, I cannot login. If I were to SSH into the server and run `mysql -u <user> -p <password>`, no errors show up and I'm immediately placed into the MySQL prompt. No problem.

However, when I try to log in with phpMyAdmin, using those exact same credentials, nothing happens. No errors, no nothing, I'm just redirected back to the login page.

Did I do something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any and all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it came down to how phpMyAdmin was configured. I had it set up to only accept requests from within the local network, instead of globally.